# How to create category and sub-category wise search button?

Tags: wordpress, button, search, categories

[Can I make this type of search button in wordpress and when clicked the search button a page will open in the new tab ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM6NW.png)

I tried various plugins and tried to search similar plugins but none worked for me. Can you suggest any plugin for it or any custom code ?

Comment: Hi Tanvir and welcome to SO. Unfortunately SO is not a coding service. We can help you with code you provide. See the [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you can ask about and the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).